# Spring Security : Authentication with Database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-security

I have implemented this way to connect and retrieve my Users from my database :

```
 @Configuration
 @EnableWebSecurity
 public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
DataSource dataSource;

@Autowired
public void configAuthentication(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {

  auth.jdbcAuthentication().dataSource(dataSource)
    .usersByUsernameQuery(
        "select username,password, enabled from users where username=?")
    .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
        "select username, role from user_roles where username=?");
}
```

So, I have my users with their roles.
In this example code, the column user_roles would be "ROLE_USER" or "ROLE_ADMIN".
I'd like to change this field by a boolean with 0 for ROLE_ADMIN and 1 for ROLE_USER.

I can't keep my user_roles due to constraints.

How could I do this ?

Comment: Please don't forget generally an admin is also an user.

Comment: Is there an Authorities tag to get ROLE_ADMIN and ROLE_USER authorization at the same time ?

Comment: You can check for AND condition in PreAuthorize or Secured annotation.

Comment: Ok. It doesn't solve my main issue with "dealing with boolean". But that is a good information.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend using boolean for Roles, because in future if there are more, then also you would have a problem. Also, a user can have multiple ROLES. It's ideal to keep a new table of roles and have many-to-one association with user. This way, for each user roles can be retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

You can adapt your query to map 0 to 'ROLE_USER' and 1 to 'ROLE_ADMIN' with [CASE operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#operator_case)

```
.authoritiesByUsernameQuery(
"select username, case when role=1 then 'ROLE_USER' else 'ROLE_ADMIN' as role from user_roles where username=?")
```

Comment: Doesn't work :/ But this is a good way to search i guess.
Do you know how can i test these request online ?

Still doesn't know why i'm doing " WHERE login = ?"

Comment: What means "doesn't work" ? (there is no *login=?* in your code) I don't see the point of *testing a database query online*